# Difference between Dynamic arrays and list c#

Tags: arrays, list, dynamic

I have a query regarding a concept.
Are dynamic arrays in c# also called list? Or they are totally different?

Answer (score 0):

C# does not have a dynamic array type. However, you can use a List as a dynamic array, given that it supports indexed access:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Hello");
list.Add("Goodbye");
Console.WriteLine(list[1]);
```

Take a look at [Generic Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's the first link I found out when looking for this difference I would like to contribute a little.

The Nitin Bisht response is not entirely wrong, but by most of programming definitions a dynamic array is a type of array that can be set when the program is already running, simply put, it's size is set during run time not in compilation.

In C# this is written as:

```
string[] myDynamicArray;
myDynamicArray = SomeMethodThatReturnsAnCollection().ToArray();
```

Other way would be a method which returns an existing array like:

```
string[] myDynamicArray;
myDynamicArray = SomeMethodThatReturnsAnArray();
```

Those are Dynamic Arrays, you don't tell your program which size it has but inside the logic of that context this will be decided.

Those Arrays in C# has the Resize method, which enables the programmer to grow the array, which I believe it was the Nitin Bisht and so many others interpretation around that question, but this is a wrong assumption, resizable is different than dynamic.

Instead of using Resize in your Array, you could just use a List type, List in C# implements an Array in it's core, [which can be seen here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646), but it also has the ability to grow in an easier approach than the Array implementation enables us with the Add(T item) List method.

List in C# would be a native Dynamic Resizable Array, some languages call similarly implementations of this structure as Vector, which are not a LinkedList with nodes and pointers for example.

Summarizing the difference in code:

```
var myList = new List<string> { "initial value" };
myList.Add("New value"); // After add, myList has this new value

var myArray = new string[] { "initial value" };
myArray.Append("New value") // after Append myArray doesnt have a new value
```

With Append() method what happens is another IEnumerable collection is created with the new value, so if you iterate through both collections you will see that the list prints out the new value but the array doesn't, in that case one way you can fix that is doing this:

```
string[] myArray;
myArray = myArray.Append("New value").ToArray(); // now it will work
```

The difference here is that myArray variable is being rewritten with the new array generated by .Append().ToArray() line, in the List example the Add() method will resize and then add the new value.

Important to note that this resize is done in a similar manner than what we did with the Append() "fixed" code, the List creates a new Array with increased size and copies it's original contents to this new Array.

You can use the resources given by the Array class to get to the same result as the Add() method implemented by List, but off course if you need that method you should just use an List instead of writing your own implementation, very rarely you would have to do it and to be honest your implementation would be probably less efficient than the already built ones.

In summary that is the difference between them, as you can see they have similarities but I would still treat them very differently.

Usually you wanna use an array when you do not expect to grow any further, if that is your case then an array is more useful since it's has less implementations and that brings a performance gain which can be good in a lot of scenarios.

If not, just use lists.